# WES 7 import pmq with a 64bit DS

Tags: windows, embedded

I'm developing an embedded OS image using Windows Embedded Standard 7 and when I try to import a PMQ file in the Image Configuration Editor using a 64 bits distribution share the import pmq option is disabled.

[64 bits DS - Import PMQ disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMjsL.jpg)

When I switch to a 32 bits DS the Import PMQ option is enabled.

[32 bits DS - Import PMQ enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JVgd.jpg)

Do you know how to enable the import PMQ option using a 64 bit distribution share?

I have worked with WXPe so I understand the general Windows Embedded creation process.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I used a 32 bits DS in order to enable the Import PMQ option, imported the PMQ and then changed the DS to 64 bits